# using StaleWhileRevalidate and BroadcastUpdatePlugin from workbox, how to notify clients of no change?

Tags: workbox

I use StaleWhileRevalidate and BroadcastUpdatePlugin from workbox and it works, my webpage gets notified when data from the server is different from the cached data.
What is the easiest way of getting notified also when they are the same?
thanks
Gabor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be a good use case for a custom Workbox plugin that implemented the [`cacheDidUpdate()` callback](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins), instead of using `BroadcastUpdatePlugin`.

([Under the hood](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/v6/packages/workbox-broadcast-update/src/BroadcastUpdatePlugin.ts), `BroadcastUpdatePlugin` implements `cacheDidUpdate()` as well.)

You will need to replicate some of the logic that you get "for free" when using `BroadcastUpdatePlugin`, but it's not too much code.

Something like:

```
const myPlugin = {
  cacheDidUpdate: async ({cacheName, request, oldResponse, newResponse}) => {
    // Use whatever combination of last-modified, etag, or other header to check.
    const isSame = oldResponse.headers.get('last-modified') ===
                   newResponse.headers.get('last-modified');
    const type = isSame ? 'CACHE_NOT_UPDATED' : 'CACHE_UPDATED';
    const message = {
      type,
      payload: {
        cacheName,
        url: request.url,
      }
    };

    const windows = await self.clients.matchAll({type: 'window'});
    for (const win of windows) {
      win.postMessage(message);
    }
  },
};
```

And then you can add `myPlugin` to any of the `workbox-strategies` that you want.